# Why am I getting name 'shared_task' is not defined error with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I am learning celery by following this [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/making-a-web-scraping-application-with-python-celery-and-django-23162397c0b6).

I created the tasks as he did and tried running the code. But I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'shared_task' is not defined
```

This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from datetime import datetime
import lxml

@shared_task
def scrape():
    try:
        ...
```

This code is working for him but I get the above mentioned error. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to import it `from celery import shared_task`

Comment: Maybe also let the author of the article know that it's missing a required import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the [celery **`shared_task`** decorator](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator) as

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def scrape():
    ...
    # your code
```